# Firebase Next.js Hosting: Unable to find 'esbuild'

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to use Firebase's new Next.js support for Hosting (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/nextjs) but I'm getting a weird error when I try to deploy. (Everything runs correctly in the local emulator suite, btw)

[Screenshot of Console output with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKcEJ.jpg)

When I try to run `firebase deploy --only hosting,functions -m "testing out next.js support"` I'm getting the error `Unable to find 'esbuild'. Install it into your local dev dependencies with 'npm i --save-dev esbuild''`. I've already added esbuild to my dev dependencies, and it seems to be installed correctly. My project uses yarn, not npm, but for the sake of testing I tried install it with npm like the error suggested, but that didn't work either.

Has anyone used Firebase Next.js hosting or figured it out since they've released it? The documentation on that page I linked above is... not great.

Comment: Did you install it in functions node_module? Show code you're trying to deploy to firebase.

Comment: The functions folder isn't being used, just default code there. That said, I just tried installing esbuild there and it installed, but the deploy command gave the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Look, no one will help you because you didn't provide anything you deploy to firebase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the repo, and branch, where this code is stored: https://github.com/FDufBos/indoor-garden/tree/harrismcc/firebase-hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the latest Firebase Tools as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/nextjs): "Firebase CLI version 11.14.2 or later".

Run `npm install -g firebase-tools` to update your version.